# PHP - Can Connect to SQL Server 2008R2 with sqlsrv_connect but not with PDO - why?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I've been trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008R2 database using PDO in PHP, using this syntax:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=xxxxxx;Database=xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
```

but each time, I try to run a query, I get **"exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. '"**

But when I try using

```
$serverName = "xxxxx";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"xxxx",
                "PWD"=>"xxxx",
                "Database"=>"xxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

The query is successful.

My PHPinfo() shows that sqlsrv is enabled in PDO drivers and the fact that sqlsrv_connect is working would seem to suggest that it's not a firewall or port opening issue. Username and password are identical in both cases.

Can anyone help suggest where I should be looking to get the PDO working, as I'd prefer to do it this way for consistency?

Comment: You can accept your own answer a day or two after posting.

Answer (score 0):

AAAARGHH, it was a syntax error in my PDO statement. Changed everything to lower case and it worked. Sorry, StackOverflow!

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if you explain what upper case stuff was causing the issue.